# Handling SSL access with multiple certificates on Google Script Servers?

Tags: ssl, google-apps-script, ssl-certificate

I have a data logger project that uploads to a Google Sheet via an Apps Script. (Running on a Mega2560 with an Adafruit ATWINC1500 WiFi breakout) This WiFi adapter requires you to manually preload a site's SSL certificates while the unit is offline.

I've figured out that it's only connecting sporadically because some of the IP addresses for "script.google.com" have different SSL certificates. (According to the serial numbers reported by an online SSL checker.)

I've been tracking about a dozen IP addresses, and I've noticed that the certificates change periodically for each IP address.

Can anyone shed any light on how often this happens? It doesn't seem related to the expiration date on the certificates.

Is there a workaround to get all the correct certificates at once? I can add multiple certificates, but I'm guessing which ones have different certs at any given moment.

Comment: Google runs its own CA. Its possible they use a let's encrypt management style where certificates are changed often for better security. Easiest is to find a better wifi stack.